# Return sum of all arguments passed to function

Tags: javascript

One way is to use arguments. I can loop over the arguments array and can return the sum of all the arguments passed.

```
function sum(){
  var sum =0; 
  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
     sum += arguments[i];
  }
   return sum;
}
sum(1,2); // returns 3
sum(1,2,3); // returns 6
```

Is there any other way to do it without using loop?

Comment: `const sum = (...args) => [...args].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other people provided answers with redundant copying of `arguments` to an array that is to be thrown away in a moment.

Instead you can do everything in one step:

```
function sum() {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}
```

If using ES2015 is an option you can have slightly nicer (subjective) implementation:

```
const sum = (...args) => [...args].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Comment: Do you need to use the Spread operator ([...args].reduce) to apply the reduce method?  It worked for me without it, i.e. args.reduce.
From the Mozilla docs:
"The arguments object is not a real array, while rest parameters are Array instances, meaning methods like sort, map, forEach or pop can be applied on it directly."

Comment: @RobGravelle that's a really nice catch. I also see now that t_dom93 does exactly that in their answer below too. I suspect those days ES2015 still was felt "new" (assuming nobody or almost nobody supported it natively?) so that ton of new language features was tricky to learn all at once :-) PS: `...` is _not_ an operator :-P

Answer (score 1):

As zerkms said, You can use `reduce` function like this

```js
alert([1, 2].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
alert([1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `Array.prototype.slice.call` to convert `arguments` into array, and use reduce to sum up numbers.

```
 function sum(){
   var total =  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(a, b) { 
   return a + b; 
   }, 0);
   return total;
}
console.log(sum(1,2)); // returns 3
console.log(sum(1,2,3)); // returns 6
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wru8mvxt/10/

Comment: Why to use extra slice when you can apply `reduce` directly to the `arguments`.

Comment: No you can't, arguments is a collection, not array, you have to convert it to array :)

Comment: You can :-) See my answer.

Comment: If you use this way you can : Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments,function(a, b) { 
   return a + b; 
   })
But not arguments.reduce(),  I assume you are talking about the first way?  Then you are right:)

Answer (score 1):

One-liner with [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) parameters:

```
const sum = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

sum(1, 3, 5, 7, 9); // 25
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arguments` is an array like object in javascript. You can use `reduce` property to convert to sum it is elements.

```
function sum() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var sum = args.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  })
  return sum;
}


console.log(sum(1, 2)); // returns 3
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // returns 6
```

You can also use `forEach` method

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6zuasc82/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you you can achieve it by using following

```
function sum(){
  var total =  0;
  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
     total += arguments[i];
  }
  return total;
}
console.log(sum(1, 2)); // returns 3
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3)); // returns 6
```

Or

Also by using `Array.prototype.reduce.call()` method.

```
function sum(){
   var total =  Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) { 
   return a + b; 
   });
   return total;
}      
console.log(sum(1, 2));    // returns 3
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));   // returns 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with ES15:

```
function sumArgs() {
    return [...arguments].reduce((acc,next)=>acc+next, 0)
};

console.log(sumArgs(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a late answer I guess but this easy method and logic will benefit others I'm sure.

```
var val = 0;
function sum(){
    for(i of arguments){
        val += i;
    }console.log(val)
}

sum(10,20,40,30,110) //Output: 210
```